# AFNetworking: is it safe to access variable outside block?

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to debug an issue when storing variable outside a block.

```
- (void) setObj : (NSString *) abc {
    [self postURL:@"..." params:@{"abc" : abc} completionHandler:^(id response) {

        [[SharedPref sharedInstance] setX:response];
        [[SharedPref sharedInstance] setAbc:abc]; <-- can we safely do this?

    } failureHandler:^(SBError *error) {

    }];
}
```

I've seen cases where when in later time I try to access abc, I'm getting empty string.

```
[[SharedPref sharedInstance] getAbc]; <-- this return empty string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be safe as long as the `abc` property in `SharedPref` is `strong` or `copy`. For `NSString*` types, it's preferred to use `copy`.

```
@interface SharedPref : NSObject
@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString* abc;
@end
```

The difference is as follows:

**`strong`**:

- `strong` indicates that the class owns the property
- `strong`  increases the reference count of the property by 1
- instance will not be released until its reference count is 0.

**`copy`**

- copy assigns a shallow copy when assigning the property by calling [copy]
- copy ensures that you're always dealing with an immutable property. If a mutable property is passed in, it will copy it. If a immutable property is passed in, it will **retain** it (you would need to dealloc it).

Comment: Ok, now does it matter if the caller for setObj is like this:
[self setObj:[[SharedPref sharedInstance] getAbc]];

Comment: What is `self` in this case? is `obj` a `strong` or `weak` property? It might help to include the scenario in the question

Comment: self AFHTTPSessionManager singleton

Comment: when I call [[SharedPref sharedInstance] setAbc:abc]; with abc being passed is essentially its current value, is it possible for it to be an empty string/nil?

Comment: If `SharedPref` has a `strong` reference to `abc` or if it has a `copy` of `abc`, then `abc` will not be `nil` unless the value is explictly set to nil or it hasn't been initialized

Comment: That's what I thought. But for some reason, in a later call [[SharedPref sharedInstance] getAbc]; gives me @"", not nil.

Comment: It seems to me that `setAbc` is being passed `@""` as an argument. Have you tried debugging the code to look for usages of `[SharedPref setAbc]`?

Comment: If you like I can take a look at the code and try to find where the problem is

Comment: Thank you, I finally figured out the issue is on the server side. False alarm :)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with what you are doing. The local variable `abc` (which is a pointer to an object) is captured by the block and `abc` inside the block will be a pointer to the same object. Assuming it's an immutable string or you never mutate the string, it should be the same string that is passed to `setAbc:`.

Given that `postURL:` is an asynchronous operation (i.e. the completion block is called at some undetermined later time), I am suspecting that you are making false assumptions about the ordering of operations. The completion block that does `setAbc:` might not have been called yet by the time you do `getAbc`, and so what you get is the initial value before you set it.